# How to encrypt tokens in database

Tags: rest, authentication, token

I develop REST API for some application and use token-auth. However I came up to one problem about storing tokens in database:

- Store them using some safe hash function like bcrypt or sha3 and display them to user only once after generation - therefore those tokens would not be backwards readable and could not be displayed to the user in the future - impact on quality for the customers
- Store them in plain-text - if database got compromited all tokens has to be regenerated - that's impact on quality for the customers as well
- Encrypt them using user's password - impossible due to database may contain multiple users which have access to tokens.

I saw that a lot of services like Google, Github and Facebook that are able to display tokens on-demand without any special procedure needed. Do they store them in plain-text or ?

Comment: If your DB gets stolen, a few regenerated tokens is what you worry about the most?

Comment: Token auth needs to be fast, as it will be performed on every api request. While hashing tokens is maaaybe a good idea (I never gave it a thought, frankly), is it worth the performance penalty and broken UX?

Comment: If it would be 'few regenerated tokens' I would not ask that question here. ;) Also why should be there some performance penalty and broken UX ? The user always send unhashed token which is then parsed and authenticated on the server-side.

Comment: Performance penalty because bcrypt is designed to be slow. And you have identified the UX problem yourself (users can't view existing tokens)

Comment: Ohh yes got your question. However, there is a problem if your DB get stolen (and sometimes it happens the way that you simply dont realize that) attacker can abuse the tokens and make some bad stuff till you regenerate new tokens. So there is definitely need to hash the tokens. Bcrypt is slow but since you use random generated unique string as token you don't have to use bcrypt with salt. You can use some function from sha-2 or sha-3 family and this should provide enough security. The only drawback is that the tokens are not backwards displayable that's why I've asked the question.

Comment: So, you just have to weigh these two concerns against one another, and decide which one you care about most. One hypothetical and the other - very real. :)